# On the Laplace transform of Beta function

Tags: integral-transforms

While trying to evaluate the Laplace transform below
$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}B(\frac{1}{2}-it,\frac{3}{2}+it)\mathrm{d}t,$$

invoking

```
LaplaceTransform[Beta[0.5-it, 1.5+it], t, s],
```

yields

$$\frac{B(\frac{1}{2}-it,\frac{3}{2}+it)}{s},$$

which is quite weird since the output of a Laplace transform has to be an exclusive function of $s$, but this output still includes $t$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like a bug, you shouldn't have s in output..I came across similar bugs, the solution was to rewrite integral using Feynam trick

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: $s$ is OK. One should not have $t$ in the output.

Comment: There were couple of bugs I ran across in laplace.transform, my workaround is using ilaplaceFeynmann and ilaplaceMellin helpers from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/286895/217

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: The definitions of these transforms are apparently not the same as that of`LaplaceTransform`. So, how do their results help here?

Comment: The `Beta` function does not include `t`, only the variable `it`. What did you intend? `i*t` or `I*t`?

Comment: @User it's an alternative way of performing Laplace transform that gets around Mathematica bugs, variation of Feynmann trick

Comment: @User ok in this case it's a typo,  not Mathematica bug

Comment: @BobHanlon: Thanks for your comment. Even doing `LaplaceTransform[Beta[0.5-i*t, 1.5+i*t], t, s]` does not return anything. (The output is printed exactly as the input.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Mathematica appears to be able to handle imaginary values for `i`

```
LaplaceTransform[Beta[1/2 - I*t, 3/2 + I*t] //
   FunctionExpand, t, s] // FullSimplify

(* (1/(8 π))(-2 π PolyGamma[0, (π + s)/(4 π)] + 
  2 π PolyGamma[0, 1/4 (3 + s/π)] + 
  I (PolyGamma[1, (π + s)/(4 π)] - PolyGamma[1, 1/4 (3 + s/π)])) *)
```

Letting `i == a*I`,

```
f[i_, s_] = ((LaplaceTransform[(Beta[1/2 - i*t, 3/2 + i*t] /. i -> a*I) //
        FunctionExpand, t, s] // FullSimplify) /. a -> i/I) // FullSimplify

(* (1/(8 i π))(-2 I π (PolyGamma[0, 1/4 + (I s)/(4 i π)] - 
     PolyGamma[0, 3/4 + (I s)/(4 i π)]) - 
  PolyGamma[1, 1/4 (1 + (I s)/(i π))] + 
  PolyGamma[1, 1/4 (3 + (I s)/(i π))]) *)
```